# How to call a local variable into another function using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, function

I am in PHP,

I have 3 Functions in PHP.

Function No 1:

```
    function get_main_sector($segment_id)
        { 
            $dbCon = new dbCon();
            $connect = $dbCon->connect();       

            $result = mysql_query($qry);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
            {
                $sourcem[] = $row;
            }
            mysql_free_result($result);
            $disconnect = $dbCon->disconnect();
            if(isset($sourcem))
                return $sourcem;
            else
                return ;
        }
```

Function No 2:

```
function getSector($sector_id)
        { 
            $dbCon = new dbCon();
            $connect = $dbCon->connect();       

            $result = mysql_query($qry);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
            {
                $sourcem[] = $row;
            }
            mysql_free_result($result);
            $disconnect = $dbCon->disconnect();
            if(isset($sourcem))
                return $sourcem;
            else
                return ;
        }
```

Function No 3:

```
function getopinions($opinions)
        { 
            $dbCon = new dbCon();
            $connect = $dbCon->connect();       

            $result = mysql_query($qry);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
            {
                $sourcem[] = $row;
            }
            mysql_free_result($result);
            $disconnect = $dbCon->disconnect();
            if(isset($sourcem))
                return $sourcem;
            else
                return ;
        }
```

My Problem is that i want to use the variable of Function 1 and Function 3 in my Function 3 as i use in a query of Function 3. But Variables of Function 2 and Function 3 is local. 
Can i call these variables in Function 3 or not? If yes then can you please tell me how i can do it?

UPDATE:
I call my first Function as:

```
if(isset( $_REQUEST['segmentID']))
{$segment_id = $_REQUEST['segmentID'];}
else {$segment_id=0;}

if(isset($segment_id) && $segment_id!=0)
{
    $main_sectors = $cont->get_main_sector($segment_id);
    echo '<select name="main_sector_id" id="main_sector_id" STYLE="width: 300px" onchange="get_sector(this.value);">';

echo '<option value="">[--Select Team----]</option>';

    if(is_array($main_sectors ) && !empty($main_sectors ))
    {
        foreach($main_sectors  as $main_sector)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$main_sector->ID.'">';

            echo $main_sector->title;

            echo '</option>';
        }
    }

echo '</select>';

    die;
}
```

Comment: What role does JavaScript play in this question?

Comment: From Javascript i pass variables in functions

Comment: PHP and JavaScript are different programming languages. They don't even run on the same computer. They simply cannot share variables. Furthermore, I can't see a single line of JavaScript in the code you've shared...

Comment: what is `$cont->`? You said functions not class; if you are using oops then use private or protected properties;

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare your variables outside from your functions, and then use these variables inside your functions as a global variables. See here how to do it:

http://php.net/manual/language.variables.scope.php